# Unable to Show Meta information with Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am practicing on a very simple Laravel project with AJAX and jQuery. I am trying to edit post and its meta information which I added before. I Tried console.log and its showing me post with meta information. Post is coming from posts table and meta information is coming from post_metas table where I added `post_id` as forign key. Post data is showing in edit modal but I am unable to put meta information in their specific fields in edit Modal.
Here is my PostController.php

```
public function edit($id)
   {

      $post = Post::with('meta')->find($id);
      if ($post) {
         return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'post' => $post,
         ]);
      } else {
         return response()->json([
            'status' => 404,
            'message' => 'Post Not Found',
         ]);
      }
   }
```

Here is Index.blade.php (jQuery AJAX Code)

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_post_btn', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var post_id = $(this).val();
 var route_url = "{{ route('blog.edit', ':id') }}";
 route_url = route_url.replace(':id', post_id);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: route_url,
    success: function(response) {
     if (response.status === 200) {
       console.log(response.post);
       $('#edit_title').val(response.post.title);
       $('#edit_excerpt').val(response.post.excerpt);
       $('#edit_content').val(response.post.content);
       $('#edit_min_to_read').val(response.post.min_to_read);
       $('#edit_meta_description').val(response.post.meta_description);
       $('#edit_meta_keywords').val(response.post.meta_keywords);
       $('#edit_meta_robots').val(response.post.meta_robots);
     } else {
       console.log(response.message);
     }
   }
  });
});
```

And This is My route:

```
   Route::get('/edit/{id}', [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('blog.edit');
```

See File Please:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta information is in the meta object:

```
$('#edit_meta_description').val(response.post.meta.meta_description);
$('#edit_meta_keywords').val(response.post.meta.meta_keywords);
$('#edit_meta_robots').val(response.post.meta.meta_robots);
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was trying from last 5 hours. you saved my time.